# Nessus Default Ports

Tags: nessus

When scanning with nessus and defining the ports, there is an option where you could simply type "default" and nessus will scan certain ports. I was wondering what the ports were? I am assuming the ports are the 100 common ports from nmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default = All common ports listed in the configuration file (/etc/services).

Extracted from [official nessus documentation page](https://www.tenable.com/blog/limiting-the-ports-probed-by-nessus-scans).